# Homogeneous children in ButtonBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I added a few children to a ButtonBox, and I wanted them not the be homogeneous. So I called ButtonBox.set_homogeneous(False) and mostly it worked. But when I resize the window bellow the minimum size, and a vertical scrollbar appears, I see there is a lot of empty space bellow the ButtonBox. I was able to fix this by individually specifying each children as non homogeneous calling ButtonBox.set_child_non_homogeneous(child, True), while also leaving in the previous call to ButtonBox.set_homogeneous(False).

My question is then, why does this happen? I set the ButtonBox's layout to EXPAND, all the space should be taken.

I made a little test code to illustrate what I'm talking about. You can try it with and without the commented line to see both cases I mentioned.

```
import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Application(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(application_id='com.stackoverflow.xor')
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)
        self.connect('startup', self.on_startup)

    def on_startup(self, app):
        self.window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)
        self.window.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.window.add(MainView(self))

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.window.show_all()


class MainView(Gtk.ScrolledWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        button_list = Gtk.ButtonBox(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        button_list.set_layout(Gtk.ButtonBoxStyle.EXPAND)
        button_list.set_homogeneous(False)
        button_list.get_style_context().remove_class('linked')
        for i in range(4):
            button = Gtk.Button()
            label = Gtk.Label('\n'.join(['test test'] * (i + 1)))
            button.add(label)
            button_list.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)
            #button_list.set_child_non_homogeneous(button, True)
        self.add(button_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app = Application()
    exit_status = main_app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is when you are adding the buttons to the box you set Expand to False.

> button_list.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)

The buttonbox having an EXPAND layout is not the same as its children expanding themselves.

EDIT: This was discussed on #gtk+ but the children should all have Expand and Fill set to True for this layout.